# Assigning PLCrashReporterCallbacks to crash reporter in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, plcrashreporter

So I'm trying to assign the callback function in swift when the app crashes. Here is, more or less, how it's done in Obj-C code.

```
/* postCrash callback */
void myCallback (siginfo_t *info, ucontext_t *uap, void *context) {
    //something to do here.
}

....
....

/* Set up post-crash callbacks */
PLCrashReporterCallbacks cb = {
    .version = 0,
    .context = nil,
    .handleSignal = myCallback
};

[crashReporter setCrashCallbacks: &cb];
```

Does anybody know how the myCallback should be implemented and assigned?